# Windows Azure Storage v5.0.0 cannot access container after upgrading from v4.3.0

Tags: azure-storage

Just upgraded Windows Azure Storage nuget package from v4.3.0 to v5.0.0 and I start to encounter exceptions being thrown when accessing the storage emulator container.

I am currently using Storage Emulator 4.0.0.0. I am not sure if v5.0.0 is not compatible with v4 version of the emulator.

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1/;");
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client .GetContainerReference("products");
container.CreateIfNotExists(accessType: BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);
```

When CreateIfNotExists is invoked the exception is thrown.

**Exception:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Comment: What version of the Azure SDK are you using? I'm using 2.7 and don't have a problem with the storage.

Comment: i am currently on 2.6. will have to upgrade and give it a try. I did not realize that there is a newer version of the SDK

Comment: Azure Storage v5 requires the emulator v4.1 which is distributed in Azure SDK 2.7

Answer (score 3):

If you are upgrading from Azure Storage v4.x to v5, take note that Azure Storage v5 works with the Azure Storage Emulator v4.1 which can be attained by upgrading to Azure SDK 2.7